# Ambiguos reference to member subscript error swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, swift2

I have this:

```
var sesionesDict:[NSString:Sesion]?
let s = sesionesDict![Sesion.dateToKey(sDate!)] as NSArray
```

The sDate returns a string, and the console is continuosly saying: Ambiguos reference to member subscript. Why?

And the Sesion.dateToKey(sDate!) returns a String value:

[image]

Comment: what does `Sesion.dateToKey(sDate!)` return?

Comment: it returns a string value

Comment: @SebastianPaduano you have declared dictionary with key `NSString` changed it to `String` and you all good to go, also in swift use Swift array instead of NSArray.

Comment: you told compiler in 1st line that it will be [NString:Session] then why you are type casting as NSArray in 2nd line ?